# Cannot create instance of Selenium webdriver.Firefox()

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.6, selenium3

I'm running Python 3.6.0 on Windows 7. I have installed Selenium version 3.3.1:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
>>> selenium.__version__
'3.3.1'
```

I also have the geckodriver executable in my Path:

```
geckodriver.exe --version
geckodriver 0.15.0
```

I'm following the steps in [the official Getting Started guide for Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

However, calling `webdriver.Firefox()` never returns an instance. It simply hangs there until I manually hit `ctrl+c`, at which point the following stack trace is printed out:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 155, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 415, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "c:\dev_env\test\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 447, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Why am I unable to create the `browser` object as indicated in the official guide?

Comment: Don't count it as an answer but look for firefox geckodriver. It may be your issue.

Comment: What is the Firefox version?

Comment: @franklinsijo Firefox version 24.8.1

Answer (score -1):

I assume you already have geckodriver downloaded. Now all you have to do is :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path to geckodriver.exe);
```